Automatically populate definitions of words
I feel like this is doable but I'm not sure how to do it...

Imagine a passage in a foreign language.

In that passage certain words are defined at the bottom.

Those definitions should come in
order of appearance in the passage, not alphabetically

Ideally, I'd like to be able to write something along the lines of
\defined{belli}{bellum, belli (n)}{war}


In the main text and have the content of the first brackets emboldened, and that of the next two appear at the bottom in the list of words.
An extension of this would be to check for repetition and still embolden but only define the word below on the first instance.
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{lineno}


\begin{document}

\begin{linenumbers}
Arma virumque canō, Trōiae quī prīmus ab ōrīs\\
Ītaliam, fātō profugus, Lāvīniaque vēnit\\
lītora, multum ille \textbf{et} terrīs iactātus \textbf{et} alto\\
vī superum saevae memorem Iūnōnis ob īram;\\
multa quoque et \textbf{bellō} passus, dum conderet urbem, \\             
inferretque deōs Latiō, genus unde Latīnum,\\
Albānīque patrēs, \textbf{atque} altae moenia Rōmae.
\end{linenumbers}

\vspace*{2em}
\textbf{Words}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
et   &  and \\
bellum, belli (n)    &  war \\
atque & and \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}


The package ekdosis has some features along these lines, though I don’t know the package well enough to make this a full answer myself.

Here is an attempt with expl3.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_gclear_new:N \g_words_prop % global prop
\seq_new:N \l_words_seq % list of words

\NewDocumentEnvironment{latintext}{}
{
  \seq_clear:N \l_words_seq % resets a local list of words
  \begin{linenumbers}
  }
  {\end{linenumbers}
  \displayList % print the local list of words
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\defined}{mO{#1}m}{
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_words_prop { #2 }
  {
    #1 % if word already in prop displays first argument
  }
  {
    % if #1 not in the global prop
    \textbf{ #1 } % prints #1 in bold
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_words_prop { #2 }{ #3 } % adds #2:#3 in global prop
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \l_words_seq { #2 } % adds #2 in local seq
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\displayList}{}
{
  \seq_if_empty:NF {\l_words_seq}{ % if local list not empty
    \vspace*{2em}
    \noindent\textbf{Words}
    \begin{description}
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_words_seq
      {
        \item [ ##1 :] \prop_item:Nn \g_words_prop { ##1 }
      }
    \end{description}
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vocabulary}{}
{
  % prints all words in order of appearance
  \seq_if_empty:NF {\g_words_prop}{
    %    \pagebreak
    \section{Vocabulary}
    \begin{description}
      \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_words_prop
      {
        \item [ ##1 :] \prop_item:Nn \g_words_prop { ##1 }
      }
    \end{description}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}
  \begin{latintext}
    Arma virumque canō, Trōiae quī prīmus ab ōrīs\\
    Ītaliam, fātō profugus, Lāvīniaque vēnit\\
    lītora, multum ille \defined{et}{and} terrīs iactātus \defined{et}{and} alto\\
    vī superum saevae memorem Iūnōnis ob īram;\\
    multa quoque et \defined{bellō}[bellum, belli]{war} passus, dum conderet urbem, \\             
    inferretque deōs Latiō, genus unde Latīnum,\\
    Albānīque patrēs, atque altae moenia Rōmae.
  \end{latintext}
  
  \begin{latintext}
    Arma virumque canō, Trōiae quī prīmus ab ōrīs\\
    Ītaliam, fātō profugus, Lāvīniaque vēnit\\
    lītora, multum ille \defined{et}{and} terrīs iactātus \defined{et}{and} alto\\
    vī superum saevae memorem Iūnōnis ob īram;\\
    multa quoque et \defined{bellō}[bellum, belli]{war} passus, dum conderet urbem, \\             
    inferretque deōs Latiō, genus unde \defined{Latīnum}[Latīnum, i]{Latin},\\
    Albānīque patrēs, \textbf{atque} altae moenia Rōmae.
  \end{latintext}
  
  \vocabulary
\end{document}



Edit
If you want to treat each block independently, try with
\NewDocumentCommand{\defined}{mO{#1}m}{
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \l_words_seq { #2 }
  {
    #1 % if word already in prop displays first argument
  }
  {
    % if #1 not in the global prop
    \textbf{ #1 } % prints #1 in bold
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \l_words_seq { #2 } % adds #2 in local seq
  }
  \prop_gput_if_new:Nnn \g_words_prop { #2 }{ #3 } % adds #2:#3 in global prop if #2 not in prop
}

I keep a global 'list' to store every unique words

Brilliant thank you - almost exactly what I need, but is there any way for a repeated word not duplicated to still be emboldened (e.g. the second et)? I realise I can just embolden it, but this way I've found errors creep in...

In the second text, you want all the defined words to be bold and to appear in the list of words? Or you want to be able to duplicate only some words?

Emboldened if given in the word list but only defined once

Does the edit answer your wishes
